# How to select a feature with the mouse click programmaticaly

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, api, c++

I am working in c++/QT 4.8.5 and the api c++ qgis 2.8.2

In my application i had top select layer with the mouse click button to get attribute value and show them in a popup windows

I see in the api online documentation taht there is two classes :

QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature and  QgsMapToolIdentify

can i use one of them to do what i want to do in my application or there is another to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching in stackexchange, on the web, and in the book "building mapping application with QGis", and try to understand
here is a simple solution taht you can use if you want 
this is a small sample of use
In my application, I load a S57 map file, When i activate the selectionLayer function via the maptool button, each time I cleck on the map the last qdebug display all the information i need

the code :

```
mIdentify =new QgsMapToolIdentify(mpMapCanvas);
mIdentify->activate();
//struct IdentifyResult *lStructResult;
QList < QgsMapToolIdentify::IdentifyResult > lResultList;
lResultList.append(mIdentify->identify(lCoord.x(),lCoord.y(),QgsMapToolIdentify::TopDownStopAtFirst, QgsMapToolIdentify::VectorLayer));

qDebug() << "size identify Qlist =" << lResultList.size();
// get the structure
QgsMapToolIdentify::IdentifyResult lStructResult = lResultList.at(0);

// get the map Layer from the structure
QgsMapLayer *lMapLayer = lStructResult.mLayer;
// get the feature from the structure
QgsFeature lFeature = lStructResult.mFeature;
// get the label
QString lLabel = lStructResult.mLabel;

qDebug() << " Label = " << lLabel << "  lFeatureId = " << lFeature.id() << "  MapLayerName = " << lMapLayer->name();
```

it is a sample test code , there is no check if the QList is empty